# update object with function call

Tags: python, methods, scope, functional-programming

I'm working with a 3rd party package that defines a result object from an expensive method call on a source object: `result_object = source_object.method(input_value)`.

I'd like to modify `result_object` inside a function call, something like this:

```
def modify_result(result_object, update_value):
    result_object = source_object.method(update_value)
```

Obviously the posted code won't work; it just creates a local `result_object` that gets discarded.  Instead, I could:

- make `result_object` nonlocal in the function, and modify it as above
- extend the `result_object` class and add a `modify_result` method
- something else?

A few clarifications.  In this context, is `result_object` considered global?  And more importantly, is there a preferred method to update `result_object` so other functions can access it?

Comment: Why don't you just return `result_object`?

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: @Alex returning `result_object` necessarily calls the expensive method.  I'd like to access a modified result without calling that every time

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird what is the cheap method?

Comment: You could put `global result_object` at the start of the function but it is sometimes frowned upon

Comment: @PeterGibson ? There is no 'cheap method'; I say expensive to indicate that the method call takes a long time

Comment: @Crawley yes, I was hoping to avoid globals

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what is the expensive vs cheap operation in your example - are you just showing the expensive operation?

In any case, it sounds like you have an expensive operation and a cheap one and you'd like to be able to use the cheap one where applicable. To do this, I would think you'd need an existing object to leverage, so I would suggest having an optional keyword argument to supply such an object, but making the return value the same result type regardless of whether it was supplied or not. Something like:

```
def process_data(new_data, existing_result=None):
    if existing_result is None:
        # create a new result object
        return make_result_via_expensive_op(new_data)
    else:
        # modify an existing result object
        existing_result.modify_via_cheap_op(new_data)
        return existing_result
```

I wouldn't recommend making it global. You can more easily pass around a reference and it's easier to follow the code.